# expand Google maps icon size

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am new to Google maps.

I have retrieved markers on google map using icon with the path value.

Here is Example : 
http://jsfiddle.net/u758rqpa/24/

Right now it is fixed slice.
But , i want it be variable.

In that example last element of markerA Array is Beamwidth.Fro example : 65,90,120 etc.
so,Now i want that marker should be expand with this width.

so, is there any possible way create slice based on this BeamWidth.

```
  var markerA = [
      ['BQ04998A_A', '-73.8186132', '40.73761121','65'],
      ['BQ04280A_B', '-73.97947631', '40.64278852','90'],
      ['BQ04673A_B', '-73.90797053', '40.63474517','120'],
      ['LI12404B_A', '-73.72630945', '40.65964026','80'],
      ['BQ04401A_C', '-73.78156774', '40.6451916','65']
      ];
```

Comment: You need to either programmatically change the path for the icon.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution :D...I thing it's scale width :)

```
// =------------------------------------------------------- Marker
/**
 * * * All function control marker * *
 * @param scale 
 */

function rowmarker(scale, width, height) {
    var goldStar = {
        path : 'M 0,3 -3,0 -' + String(width / 2) + ',0 -' + String(width / 2)
                + ',-' + String(height + 19 / scale) + ' ' + String(width / 2)
                + ',-' + String(height + 19 / scale) + ' ' + String(width / 2)
                + ',0 3,0 z',
        fillColor : '#ffffff',
        fillOpacity : 1,
        scale : scale,
        draggable : 'true',
        strokeColor : '#009956',
        strokeWeight : 4
    };
    return goldStar;
}
```

So my function try reside marker with path,

this will raw a squares with (width, height value), so you can view example from this

[View Example](http://jsfiddle.net/u758rqpa/31/)

Comment: can you please tell me this type for my path value ? because i have just only Beamwidth value.

Comment: this is. Beamwidth, path  is string Beamwidth.